# jQuery append wont trigger more than once

Tags: jquery, select

The problem is, than if I change value on **select** item it append it to the texarea perfectly. But if i then write something next to appended content and try to use **select** again, it wont append it to textarea.

You can check my **JSFiddle** code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5NY3T/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use append, use `val`, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NY3T/1/

Comment: Thanky you very much. Can you tell me, is there any reason why append wont work at such situations? Thanks

Comment: `Append` is used to append one DOM node to another. Textarea can't have child nodes.